# Step By Step Tax Information On Magento 2

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class, shipping-tax, tax-calculation

To start with the Magento Tax, 
For New User: You should know the following,

**Basic setting for Tax/Vat Configuration**

1.Customer Tax Class
2.Product Tax Class
3.Shipping Tax Class
4.Tax Rates
5.Tax Zones

Combine them all and Create Tax Rule, Once done, set default destination.

**Brief of above settings:**

**Customer Tax Class:** Customer tax classes are useful to apply the different tax rate to different types of Customer Groups. You can create as many customer tax classes as you need, and assign them to Customer Group.

For Eg: In some Administration, wholesale transactions are not taxed, but retail transactions are. You can associate members of the Wholesale Customer group with the Wholesale tax class.

**Setting up the Customer tax Classes:**
Login in Magento Admin Panel
Create the Customer Tax class
Link it with the customer Group here Store> Other Settings > Customer Group
[image]

**Product Tax Class:** Product Tax Classes are used in calculations to determine the correct tax rate is applied in the shopping cart. When you create a product, it is assigned to a specific tax class. Taxable Goods is a default class in Magento.
For example, food might not be taxed, or be taxed at a different rate.
That is, You could have different Tax rates on different products such as Clothes, Cosmetics, Medicines, Food Items, home appliances.

**Setting up the Product Tax class:**
Login in Magento Admin Panel
Go to Stores > Tax Rules > Add new Rules > Additional Settings

**Tax rates and Zones:** There is a facility in Magento to define tax according to Country, States, Zip codes.
[image]

**Setting up the Tax Rates and Zones:**
Login in Magento Admin Panel
Store > Configuration > Tax Rates and Zones
[image]

**Tax Rule:** 
Important fields to set a Tax Rule
1. Tax Rate: Defines the rate percentage (%) of Tax applied.
2. Customer Tax Class: Defines Tax for Customers.
3. Product Tax Class: Defines Tax for Product.
4. Priority: Prioritize the Tax Rules as in which one to be applied on top of every other one. Tax rates at the same priority are added, others are compounded.
[image]

**Default Destination/ Country**
You need to set up default destination here
Store > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Default Tax Destination Calculation. 
[image]

**Tax Configuration**

Store > Configuration > Sales > Tax

**Calculation Setting:** 
As per the requirement of your client, you can change the calculation settings here, There is the various combination to calculate/ the tax here.
[image]

**Price Display Setting:**
You can set up, what price you want to show on you Catalog pages (Including Tax, Excluding Tax, Including Tax and Excluding Tax)
[image]

**Shopping Cart Display Setting:**
You can set up, what price you want to show on you Cart pages (Including Tax, Excluding Tax, Including Tax and Excluding Tax)
[image]

**Order, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Setting:**
You can set up, what price you want to show in Magento Admin Order, Invoice and Credit Memos (Including Tax, Excluding Tax, Including Tax and Excluding Tax)
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Voted for close, this is not blog site

Comment: Hi Chandani, Please explain in more details

Comment: Please explain the issue